# what is wrong with my word boundary regex?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, word-boundary

I have the following little Python script:

```
import re

def main ():
    thename = "DAVID M. D.D.S."
    theregex = re.compile(r"\bD\.D\.S\.\b")
    if re.search(theregex, thename):
        print ("you did it")
main ()
```

It's not matching.  But if I adjust the regex just slightly and remove the last . it does work, like this:

```
\bD\.D\.S\b
```

I feel I'm pretty good at understanding regexes, but this has be baffled.  My understanding of \b (word boundary) should be the a zero width match of non alpha-numeric (and underscore).  So I would expect

```
"\bD\.D\.S\.\b"
```

to match:

```
D.D.S.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Avoid double escaping with `r'\bD\.D\.S\.\b;` but `\b` (word boundary) can't be matched after dot since dot is a non-word character.

Comment: Does that mean I can only use \b next to a word character?  So if I have "hyper!"  I can't have a ever have a regex "hyper!\b"

Comment: Yes that's correct since word has already ended at `!`. `\b` can be used to assert position between `hyper` and `!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't do what you might think it does.

```
r"\bD\.D\.S\.\b"
```

Here is an [explanation of that regex](https://regex101.com/r/DUQuIc/1), with the same examples that are listed below:

```
D.D.S.   # no match, as there is no word boundary after the final dot
D.D.S.S  # matches since there is a word boundary between `.` and `S` at the end
```

Word boundaries are zero-width matchers between word characters (`\w`, which is `[0-9A-Za-z_]` plus other "letters" as defined by your locale) and non-word characters (`\W`, which is the inversion of the previous class).  Dot (`.`) is not a word character, so  `D.D.S.`   (note trailing whitespace) has word boundaries (only!) in the following places:  `\bD\b.\bD\b.\bS\b.`   (I didn't escape the dots because I'm illustrating the word boundaries, not making a regular expression).

I assume you are trying to match a end of line or whitespace.  There are two ways to do that:

```
r"\bD\.D\.S\.(?!\S)"   # by negation: do not match a non-whitespace
r"\bD\.D\.S\.(?:\s|$)" # match either a whitespace character or end of line
```

I've refined the above regex explanation link to [explain the negation example above](https://regex101.com/r/DUQuIc/2) (note the first ends in `…/1` while the second ends in `…/2`; feel free to further experiment there, it is nice and interactive).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed write-up.  Every time I think I have regexes figured out I stumble upon something like this :)

Comment: "Word boundaries are zero-width matchers between word characters"  Does that mean this would never make sense:  "!\b!" because either side of the \b isn't a word character?  If that's the case it all become clear to me.

Comment: `\b` is a zero-width matcher, so it matches the boundary between `D` and `.` in `D.` without consuming any width.  You're right: the regex `!\b!` is guaranteed to fail because there can't possibly be a word boundary between two exclamation points.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much.  I feel like I've leveled up :)

Answer (score 0):

- `\.\b` matches `.bla` - checks for word character after `.`
- `\.\B` the opposite matches `bla.` but not `bla.bla` - checks for non word after `.`

```
\bD\.D\.S\.\B
```

Comment: This will also match `D.D.S..` and I'm not sure that was desired.